# Load array with fixed pattern of data

Tags: arrays, f#

I have a delimited string of data, e.g.

```
a~b~c~d~e~f~g~h~i~j~k~l~... 
dog~cat~fish~parrot~mother~father~child~grandparent~...
hello~hi~greetings~yo
```

I am wanting to load the data into an array/seq of records of type

```
type myType {
    first: string;
    second: string;
    third: string;
    fourth:string;
}
```

so I'd end up with 3 objects in the array/seq. I've been messing around with for loops to do this, but it feels pretty imperative. How would I achieve this using a functional idiom?

EDIT: I should have clarified that the delimited data could be of variable length although the number of delimited items should always be a multiple of 4. So, with each iteration, I am looking to strip 4 pieces of the input data load them into the type and once all the data has been consumed, return an Array/seq.

EDIT 2: So I ended up with something like this

```
let createValues(data: string) =               
    let splitValues(valueString) = 
        let rec splitData acc = function
            | a :: b :: c :: d :: xs -> splitData ({ first=a; second=b; third=c; fourth=d } :: acc) xs
            | [] -> acc
            | _ -> failwith "uneven data"
        splitData [] valueString
    splitValues (data.Split [|'~'|] |> Array.toList)
```

Thx

Comment: You should post your current solution and ask how it could be more functional.  It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing without code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your type contains only single characters - assuming the data always consists of single characters the delimiter is unnecessary. Here is one way to map the data into a list of your types, this will only work if the amount of characters in the data is divisible by 4, but will work with variable sized inputs.

```
let data = "a~b~c~d~e~f~g~h~i~j~k~l~m~n~o~p"

let splitData data =
    let rec aux acc = function
        | a::b::c::d::xs -> aux ({ first=a; second=b; third=c; fourth=d } :: acc) xs
        | [] -> acc
        | _ -> failwith "uneven data"
    aux [] data

let output = splitData (data.Replace("~","").ToCharArray() |> Array.toList)
```

Comment: Excellent. Thx Ross. Seeing the input string as a list, rather than data which happened to be delimited, was the bit I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

Despite great answers been given already, if you need to be sure that input data format is exactly to your spec, you could parse it like this:

```
let readObjects inputString =
    let rec readObjectsAux input =
        seq {
            match input with
            | a :: '~' :: b :: '~' :: c :: '~' :: d :: rest ->
                yield { first = a; second = b; third = c; fourth = d }
                match rest with
                | '~' :: rest -> yield! (readObjectsAux rest)
                | [] -> ()
                | _ -> failwith "bad input"
            | [] -> ()
            | _ -> failwith "bad input"
        }
    readObjectsAux <| (List.ofSeq inputString)
```

This way you are ensuring that your characters always come in quartets, and they are always separated by exactly one `'~'`.

Comment: Many Thx. Very helpful. I'll be using bits of your reply in conjunction with Ross'

Answer (score 2):

If each field is exactly one `char` (in which case, I don't see the point in the delimiter so I've omitted it), you could do this:

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\data.txt")
  |> Array.mapi (fun n line ->
    match line.ToCharArray() with
    | [|a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l|] ->
      let t1 = {first=a; second=b; third=c; fourth=d}
      let t2 = {fifth=e; sixth=f; seventh=g; eighth=h}
      let t3 = {ninth=i; tenth=j; eleventh=k; twelfth=l}
      (t1, t2, t3)
    | _ -> failwithf "Can't parse line %d" (n+1))
```

If the delimiter is needed, you could change it to:

```
    match line.Split('~') with
    | [|a;b;c;d;e;f;g;h;i;j;k;l|] ->
      let t1 = {first=a.[0]; second=b.[0]; third=c.[0]; fourth=d.[0]}
      ...
```

Comment: Many thx for this. Sorry I wasn't clear enough to start with!